This data set is too large for grid
My current project involves a table with Excel formulas that reference a csv file that is constantly updating. However, this csv has recently grown too large to fully display as a connection. Therefore, the formulas are not accurately calculating. What are my options to make things work?

How large are we talking about ?

3 million rows I think

Well, it's obviously way too much, your best option is too clean it up, do you really need 3 million rows ?

Do the calculations in power query. Use power bi. Powerpivot can also handle that much data depending on your version of Excel and available memory.
